# How do I join identical columns while also keeping separate unique columns from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables, E and P.

E:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val A | Val C | Val E | Val X |
| Val B | Val D | Val F | Val Y |

P:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val A | Val C | Val E | Val Z |
| Val B | Val D | Val F | Val K |

where Columns 1, 2, and 3 in both tables are identical in terms of both the name of the column and the values but column 4 in table E and column 5 in table P both have unique values.

How do I join these two tables so that I get:

EP:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val A | Val C | Val E | Val X | Val Z |
| Val B | Val D | Val F | Val Y | Val K |

I have tried:

```
select  

p.[Col 1],

p.[Col 2],

p.[Col 3],

e.[Col 1],

e.[Col 2],

e.[Col 3],

p.[Col 5],

e.[Col 4]

from p

left join e on p.[Col 3] = E.[Col 3] and p.[Col 2] = e.[Col 2] and p.[Col 1] = e.[Col 1]

group by p.[Col 1], p.[Col 2], p.[Col 3], e.[Col 1], e.[Col 2], e.[Col 3]
```

But what I get is:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val A | Val C | Val E | Val A | Val C | Val E | Val X | Val Z |
| Val B | Val D | Val F | Val B | Val D | Val F | Val Y | Val K |

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? (You aren't using any aggregate functions.)

Comment: You may want to `UNION` the result sets from each table, and in table 1 put nulls for col 5 and in table 2 put nulls for column 4

Comment: Why do you SELECT 8 columns when you only want five?

Comment: Add some more sample data for each table, also non-matching values, and also adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over complicating it substantially here.

```
    SELECT 
        p.[Col 1],
        p.[Col 2],
        p.[Col 3],
        e.[Col 4] AS [Col 4],
        p.[Col 4] AS [Col 5],
    FROM p INNER JOIN 
        e ON (p.[Col 3] = E.[Col 3] and p.[Col 2] = e.[Col 2] and p.[Col 1] = e.[Col 1])
```

Comment: Indeed I was... This is exactly what I wanted and much more concise. Thank you